# Winforms: How can I programmatically display the last item in a C# listview when there are vertical scrollbars?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar

How can I programmatically display the last item in a C# listview when there are vertical scrollbars?  I've studied every method associated with listviews and can't find anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not actually easy/possible to scroll the list view.  You need to tell the item to make sure it's visible.

```
var items = listView.Items;
var last = items[items.Count-1];
last.EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: This code works, but a horizontal bar shows up and conceals it on my CE device (due to the limited size).  Any way to diable horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: You need to take into account the vertical scrollbar width. Your columns should't use all the width of your ListView... save a little bit for the vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 6):

```
this.listView1.Items[this.listView1.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
```

Answer (score 1):

WINFORMS:

Did you try setting the Selected value to TRUE in the last item in the Items collection of the ListView?

I think that doing this will focus on the last item... scrolling down if it is necesary.
But I did't tryed myself.

EDIT:
**This will do the trick:**

```
Me.ListView1.Items(Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1).EnsureVisible()
```

Comment: It set the focus but did not auto scroll.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ListViewItem.EnsureVisible()

Answer (score 0):

WPF or WinForms?

In WPF, you get the `ListViewItem` and call `BringIntoView` on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to using a windows function to hide the horizontal and force vertical to be shown at all times:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/4aa4dade-53a2-4e2e-a8b4-b4980da1f39c/

Answer (score 0):

The following hack will both select and show the last ListView item.
Not sure why this works but it works.

```
listview.SelectedIndices.Clear();  
listview.FocusedItem = listview.Items[listview.Items.Count - 1];  
listview.FocusedItem.Selected = true;  
listview.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
    listview.FocusedItem.EnsureVisible(); 
});
```

Also, if you don't want a horizontal scroll bar to show, you need to resize ListView columns to fit the ListView's `ClientArea` width before calling `BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom control that inherits the ListView but since it does not expose the inner ListView I had no way to utilize the above mentioned `items...EnsureVisible()` solution.

I solved as sort of work around by sending the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> keys directly to that control to manually fix the scroll to bottom:

```
logMsgList.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^{END}");
```